# Need an object to become 'unclickable' behind certain objects. As3 Flash Cs4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hide, target

How can I make a clickable movieclip 'hide' behind another object. Eg.. I have a rabbit movieclip - he is clickable - as he walks behind a tree(MC) he needs to hide behind that tree.

At the moment, if I click on the tree - the mouse click seems to ignore the tree completely and I can still click the unseen rabbit.

```
var HitCount:Number = 10;
var RabbitG1X:Number = 0;
var RabbitG1Y:Number = 0;
var RabbitG2X:Number = 0;
var RabbitG2Y:Number = 0;





Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
function follow(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    Cursor_mc.x =mouseX;
    Cursor_mc.y=mouseY;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{    
     if (Cursor_mc.hitTestObject(RabbitG1_mc))
     {

  trace ("you fed rabbit1 ");
  RabbitG1_mc.x = RabbitG1X + 5000;
  RabbitG1H_mc.x = RabbitG1X + 1271.85;
  RabbitG1H_mc.y = RabbitG1Y + 184.05;
  HitCount = HitCount -1;
  Dec_txt.text = "" + HitCount + "";
  }



   if (Cursor_mc.hitTestObject(RabbitG2_mc))
 {

  trace ("you fed rabbit2 ");
  RabbitG2_mc.x = RabbitG2X + 5000;
  RabbitG2H_mc.x = RabbitG2X + 1271.85;
  RabbitG2H_mc.y = RabbitG2Y + 184.05;
  HitCount = HitCount -1;
  Dec_txt.text = "" + HitCount + "";
  }
   if (HitCount ==0)
  {
  trace("You fed all the rabbits");
  }
   }
```

I tried adding this to the tree mc to see if I could kill the mouse when it moved over tree.

```
Tree2MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, solid);

function solid(e:MouseEvent):void{
 Tree2MC.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

However, it isn't ideal. I really need a clickable object to hide if it goes behind another object on the stage. So if he is half hidden and I click on the part of the MC still revealed, it will click.. And it didn't work.

Comment: hitTestObject has nothing to do with mouseevent, it's a 2D comparison of object bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to use the hitTest code to figure out what was clicked.  You can use the mouse event's `.target` property to figure that out - that will also solve your issue of knowing if the tree was clicked or the rabbit.

For example:

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {    
    if (event.target == RabbitG1_mc){
        //.....do you stuff

    if (event.target == RabbitG2_mc){
```

Now, one thing to point out, is the `.target` of an event could also be a child object of a rabbit (if your rabbit MC had other objects inside it).  So to make sure it's consistent, you can do something like this when you initialize your rabbits:

```
RabbitG1_mc.mouseChildren = false;
RabbitG2_mc.mouseChildren = false;
```

---

Alternatively, you could just add mouse event listeners to the rabbits directly instead of one listener on the stage that will catch everything.  This way, if an object (tree) is in front of them (and is mouse enabled), the click event will dispatch on the tree instead of the rabbit and the `clickHandler` won't run.

```
RabbitG1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
RabbitG2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //event.currentTarget is a reference to what you attached the listener to
    switch(event.currrentTarget){
        case RabbitG1_mc: 
           //..do your code
           break;
        case RabbitG2_mc: 
           //..do your code
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Batman.. All in a day's work huh? I couldn't get the second code to work - kept getting errors .. But the first code works like a dream..But only when we killed the mouse children. (RabbitG1_mc.mouseChildren = false;)